# Clojure: How to use variables in regular expressions?

Tags: clojure

What is the correct way to use variables in a regular expression? E.g.:

```
(def var "/")
(split "foo/bar" #var)
```

should give

```
=> ["foo" "bar"]
```

But it doesn't work this way. So how do I do that? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(def my-re (java.util.regex.Pattern/compile "/")) ; to turn a string into a regex
;; or just
(def my-re #"/") ; if the regex can be a literal

(clojure.string/split "foo/bar" my-re)
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: (re-pattern "/") will do as well, slightly more concise than (java.util.regex.Pattern/compile "/")

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`re-pattern`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-pattern) :

```
(def var "/")                ; variable containing a string
(def my-re (re-pattern var)) ; variable string to regex

(clojure.string/split "foo/bar" my-re)
```

Or, using a thread-last macro :

```
(->> "/"
     (re-pattern)
     (clojure.string/split "foo/bar"))
```